# Chrome tooltip style changed in last version

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I tried this in two machines and they work the same.

In Chrome, the tooltip style changed, instead of the usual greish background color now it's white, and the bottom and right borders disappeared. This is an example. Is this a feature or a defect?

[image]

Comment: Can you test it again and specify the version? I can't reproduce this on version 78.0.3904.108 and 79.0.3945.79 (just updated).

Comment: This is the version I'm running: Version 79.0.3945.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Any extensions? And OS?

Comment: Katalon and Postman extensions, but installed recently after I posted this question in September. OS Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested tooltips in Chrome and found that their behavior was inconsistent and
apparently depended on the included text.
Not all tooltips lost both bottom and right borders, as some only lost one
of the two.

I believe that this is a display bug in Chrome, where the borders are
painted first and then is painted the text.
The calculations for the size required for painting the text seem
to be incorrect, so that the borders are overwritten by the text,
sometimes only on the bottom and sometimes also on the right.

Besides the wrong size calculations, another problem here is the usage of
opaque background for the text.
If the text was written using transparent background, this would not have
happened (or perhaps the text would have been laid on top of the
border lines).

This is a bug (or two bugs) which should be signaled to the Chromium team.

Comment: Thanks, it was already reported [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1033862&q=tooltip&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)